# android - image to be scrolled with listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

in my app i want to show a page with a single image at the top and list of names below it. The image may cover 80% of the screen, i don't want to give heights for either image view or for the listview.

I have tried in the following way, i have two array list. One array contains the url of the image and the other text to be displayed as follows

```
array 1 = ["http://....","A","B","C","D"......]
```

the next array contains the 0 and 1 as follows

```
array 2 = [0,1,1,1,1.......]
```

Following is my list view code

```
public class listViewHolder 
            {
                ImageView product_hold_image;
                TextView product_hold_subHeading;
            }
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                listViewHolder holder = null;
                try 
                {
                    if (convertView == null) 
                    {
                        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lst_ly, null);           
                        holder = new listViewHolder();
                        holder.product_hold_image      = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        holder.product_hold_subHeading = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lst_textView1);

                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        holder = (listViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }
                    if(data.get(position).contains("0"))
                    {
                        img = data_phonetxt.get(position).toString();           
                        img = img.replaceAll(" ","%20");        

                        Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(img);
                        holder.product_hold_image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                    populateListData(holder, position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e("list view holder - error: ",""+e);  
                }
                return convertView;
            }
            public void populateListData(listViewHolder viewHolder, int position) 
            {   
                if(data.get(position).contains("1"))
                {
                    Log.e("data.get(position).contains(0) ","is false");
                    viewHolder.product_hold_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.product_hold_subHeading.setText(data_phonetxt.get(position).toString());
                }
                else if(data.get(position).contains("0"))
                {
                    img = data_phonetxt.get(0).toString();          
                    img = img.replaceAll(" ","%20");        

                    Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(img);
                    viewHolder.product_hold_image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            }
```

According to the above code for the first time i use to get the image in top and all the text below it but when i scroll the list view from top to bottom and when i move to the top again the image is been replaced by some text,

Is there any other easy way to get this, any suggestions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the solution by using a separate views in a ListActivity.

Use a separate view as an image view and add the image view in header of the listview

```
localListView = getListView();
                    LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService("layout_inflater");
                    View localView1 = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.img1, localListView, false);
                    this.mImageView = ((ImageView)localView1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

                    localListView.addHeaderView(localView1, null, false);
                    localListView.setCacheColorHint(0);
```